# Is it possible to reuse a graphics card from an old laptop in a new laptop, together with the existing graphics card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have a Dell G3 laptop with a broken screen which has a NVIDIA GTX 1060 and a Dell XPS laptop which has a NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti. Is it in any way possible to pull out the graphics card from the G3 and make use of it in my new laptop for gaming? Perhaps by an external dock or something?

Comment: Those graphics adapters are often permanently attached as chips on the motherboard. If you'd like to know more, since there are dozens of G3 models. https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/19#q=g3&sort=relevancy&f:langFacet=[en] please provide either the Service Tag, or the complete model part number from the sticker underneath.

Comment: Are you positive of those model numbers, neither of those, are parts for a laptop.